# При клике по строке в таблице передать значение в модальное окно . Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Не получается сделать так что бы при клике на товар в таблице, передать его бренд и код в модальное окно (без перезагрузки страницы). Сейчас открывается окно но с пустым полем.В правильном ли я направлении? Буду очень благодарна за помощь.

goods.php

```
  <td><span class="btn btn-primary request_goods" code="<?=$goods[Code]?>" brand="<?=$goods[BrandName]?>"> Запросить товар</span>   
  </td>
```

footer.php

```
 <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    ...
    "CATEGORY_BRAND_VALUE" => $_POST["goods_brand"], // Здесь передаю значение в модальное окно 
    ...
  )?>




<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.request_goods').click(function() {
       $.post( 'footer.php', {brand: $(this).attr("brand"), code: $(this).attr("code")} );
       $.ajax({    url: "footer.php",      success:
       $('#request_analog').modal('show') });
       });
   });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не нужно посылать аякс запросы для этого

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.request_goods').click(function() {
        $('#request_analog').find('.brand').text($(this).attr("brand"));
        $('#request_analog').find('.code').text($(this).attr("code"));
        $('#request_analog').modal('show') });
    });
});
```

find('.code') - это пример как можно найти элемент, в данном случае по классу.

.text() - задает текст для элемента, вроде span или div. Для input надо использовать val()